# Add Favicon in RSS feeds in Django

Tags: django, rss

I have used RSS Feed with django,

I have refer the below link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/

And properly created the RSS, but Now I want to add the favicon for the RSS feeds pages.

Can anybody suggest me?

Thanks.

My code is:

**In feeds/feed.py**

```
class LatestArticlesFeed(Feed):

    title='News -RSS'
    link='/' # URI of site
    description='Latest Article Entries'

    def get_object(self, request):
        category_slug = request.GET.get('category_slug')
        category = Category.objects.get(slug = category_slug)

    def items(self, obj):
        article_list = Article.objects.filter(category =obj)[:10]
        return article_list

    def item_title (self, item):
        return item.headline
```

In urls.py

```
(r'^feeds/article/$', LatestArticlesFeed()),
```

Comment: have you tried to add icon in your feedgenerator?

Comment: I am not using any custom feedgenarator.

Comment: Ok, in your `LatestArticlesFeed`, have you tried to put `icon='url'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have add the icon like this,
   icon="/media/images/favicon.ico" after description.
Is it correct?
Still this icon is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your urls.py file:

```
(r'^favicon\.ico$', 
 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', 
 {'url': '/media/favicon.ico'}),
```

If you're talking about a WebFaction Django install, you should be able to edit the .conf file in the apache2 directory in your app's directory and add a *Redirect /favicon.ico http://example.com/static/favicon.ico*

Note that you can also specify a favicon in the HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply, I have tried this, but its not working.

Comment: I have edited my question, added the code which i used, link tag is already present in my website base file, but that favicon is not applied for RSS feeds page.

Comment: when i review the page source of the RSS feeds page, which contains the <?xml> and <rss> tag which include <channel> tag which contains the data. there will be no head tag in it.

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.5 simple views like from Plymorphin's answer don't exist anymore. Modern approach to do this is presented below.

Assuming you have your favicon with other static files at: **your_app/static/favicon.ico** you can add to main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags import staticfiles
from django.views.generic import base

...

urlpatterns += patterns(
    '',
    url('^favicon\.ico$',
        base.RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles.static('favicon.ico'))),
)
```

or extend existing patterns inline.